# C#, replacing special character in query

Tags: c#

I have a record in a database containing special characters like `&,'` (apostrophe).

The record look like this.. `stack'overflow`.

In my query I have written like this.

```
where name = ' " +name+ " ' ";
```

Suppose the name is `stack'overflow` - then it gives me a syntax error.

How to solve it?

I am using C#

Comment: **Important:** You should also be using parameterized queries for the records which don't have special characters.  You should go through your code and fix this everywhere, not just for this specific call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use parameters.

For more information, consult the documentation for whatever you're using.

Comment: i am using %% with the name so it can search for a specified string..in this case how to do it? if not parameterized query then it is like '%"+name+"%'", but in your case how to do it?

Comment: @safi: You can still use parameters.  Just put the `%`s in the parameter.

Comment: my parameter name is name, so it will be like, sqlcmd1.parameter.addwithvalue("name",?) i am confuse with this

Comment: @safi: Just pass `"%" + name + "%"` as the parameter value

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very unclear but the answer is almost certainly going to be not to include data in SQL statements. Use a parameterized query instead, so you don't need to worry about performing any escaping etc yourself.

As an example, have a look at the [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) documentation - but be aware that different DB providers use different approaches to parameters (e.g. named vs positional).

Comment: i am using %% with the name so it can search for a specified string..in this case how to do it? if not parameterized query then it is like '%"+name+"%'", but in your case how to do it?

Comment: @safi: You'd use a LIKE clause that's parameterized instead. You'd still need to think about any escaping specifically for LIKE parameters, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 2):

Dont append text into a query.  Search google for SQL Injection. Its a big problem and you shouldnt be doing this. You are potentially leaving yor application open to serious attack.

One solution is to use SQL parameters instead in your queries.  Take a look here for further information : [Adding Parameters to Commands](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use [parameterized queries](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+parameterized+query).  They will handle the escaping of special characters for you and will help guard against SQL injection attacks.  They also provide a better mechanism for the SQL server to cache an execution path to improve performance.

Never, ever, *ever* use concatenated SQL.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this would be to use parameterized queries. String building for SQL can be pretty dangerous if the data is not santized properly beforehand.

Try something like this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = @p_name";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_name",yourTextItem);
```

Updated for your situation:

```
string myName = TextBox1.Text;

string query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name LIKE %@p_name%";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_name",myName);
```

Comment: i am using %% with the name so it can search for a specified string..in this case how to do it? if not parameterized query then it is like '%"+name+"%'", but in your case how to do it?

Comment: Okay, so you would just write this into your query as normal, surrounding the parameter. You could even append it to "yourTextItem" if you wished.

Comment: my parameter name is name, so it will be like, sqlcmd1.parameter.addwithvalue("name",?) i am confuse with this

Comment: @safi - I have updated my original post with the adjusted example. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

replace `"'"` with `"''"` in your name variable before passing in and you should be fine.

EDIT:

Yes This would just be a temporary solution. To permanantly get rid of your problem please use parameterized query.

Comment: Or you can use @SLaks' or @JonSkeet's suggestion.

Comment: -1 for suggesting this, even as a temporary solution.  Temporary solutions have a bad habit of becoming permanent.